# Sorting text field in PostgreSQL is not sorting as expected

Tags: string, postgresql, sorting, locale, collator

I have a text column in PostgreSQL that I am ordering by in `ASC` order and it is returning the following order:

`SELECT column_A FROM table ORDER BY column_A ASC`:

| column_A |
| --- |
| IKvap06:52:22.52 |
| i.lost.all.my.tacos |
| IQKPb06:55:51.53 |

But I was expecting this:

| column_A |
| --- |
| i.lost.all.my.tacos |
| IKvap06:52:22.52 |
| IQKPb06:55:51.53 |

Any ideas as to why/how this happening? Using locale: `en_US.UTF8`

I double checked the locale in the database instance to make sure it was `en_US.UTF8`. I can't seem figure out why I am getting this sort.

Comment: `order by lower(column_a)` to ignore upper/lower case

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, That won't work: `select lower('i.lost.all.my.tacos') < lower('IKvap06:52:22.52'); f`. This is down to locale sorting rules. Per: `select lower('i.lost.all.my.tacos') < lower('IKvap06:52:22.52' collate "C"); t`.

Comment: This is definitely weird. https://dbfiddle.uk/SYzS8t_H is a fiddle.

Comment: Worth reading, I guess: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_do_my_strings_sort_incorrectly.3F

Comment: Why are you expecting what you are expecting?  That is not how the default collation for en_US is defined.  It is weird to use a specific locale but expect that that locale not be used.

Comment: @jjanes My company's database instance is set to that locale. I want understand the sort that I am seeing so that I can replicate is somewhere else. In general, that is what I "would" expect but the main purpose for the question is to understand.

Comment: On the linux command line, I can replicate your shown sort order with `sort` as long as LC_ALL is unset and LANG is set to 'en_US.UTF8'.  Your expected sort order I can replicate with LC_ALL=C using `sort -f`.